# What is the difference between skimage view_as_window and sklearn extract_patch_2d, in the context of extracting array of patches from an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I have an array of 2D images; an array of [n x w x h], n being the number of images. I want to extract patches from each 2D image. A 2D image would not be divided equally by the patch size (meaning I should use padding). I do not want overlapping patches. I came across two functions in skimage and sklearn for this: [view_as_window()](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) and [extract_patches_2d()](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html). My questions are,

1. Why there are two methods?
2. Which one suits my use case the most?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to extract patches from a 2D image, `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d` is the right choice, because it does this and nothing else, and you can expect it to have been optimised for that task.

Though something like `skimage.util.view_as_windows` may have a similar outcome for the 2D case you're interested in, it is not the specific purpose it was written for. This function provides a rolling window view of an n-dimensional array, and although in your case 'n' may be 2, it works for any n.

As a result, `skimage.util.view_as_windows` is likely not optimised for the use case you have in mind, or may get weighed down with additional logic in the future that would affect your use case only negatively.

Even if `sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d` ended up calling `skimage.util.view_as_windows` in the background, it would still make sense to use the more specific call, to benefit from potential future optimisation or avoid divergence from your use case.

As an analog consider a math library that has a function to solve a quadratic equation, and another function that can solve any polynomial equation under certain conditions. If you only need to solve quadratic equations, you'd pick the first one, even though the second one would work as well. But *why* both exist is obvious, and similar reasoning applies for the case you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One more thing I am unclear about is whether the view_as_windows works in a more memory-efficient way compared to the extract_patches_2d. Any comments?

Comment: Without testing or really looking into the source deeply, I couldn't say. However, just from what these functions are doing, I would expect `skimage.util.view_as_windows` to be more efficient. It is however possible that `skimage.util.view_as_windows` trade space for speed and is in fact a bit more wasteful with space to achieve greater speed. If you need to know for sure, your best bet is to run a few tests with varying image and patch sizes, and with a large enough number of samples to eliminate small data noise.